# How to communicate size change to SwiftUI subview

Tags: ios, swiftui

In my SwiftUI code I have an element with a fixed height but a dynamic width that should be set depending on the requirements to the element. If no width is set the element should be only as wide as the children expect it to be.

How do I propagate the size change to the encapsulated view?

Example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .frame(height: 48)
            .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.blue))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            MyView()
                .frame(width: 300)
            MyView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your needs, here is possible solution

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct MyView: View {
    var width: CGFloat? = nil

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .frame(height: 48)
            .frame(minWidth: width)
            .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.blue))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            MyView(width: 300)
            MyView()
        }
    }
}
```